# The model item passed is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List but this dictionary requires 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-controller

I am newbie and getting the error model item passed into directory is of type system.cllection.generic.list but this directory requires system.collection.ienumerable

Please help me to resolve this error.
I am pasting my controller and view here

Controller

```
      public ActionResult DisplayComment()
    {
        var result = Manager.GetUsersWhoHaveConsumedFreeCredit();
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var callHistory = serializer.Deserialize<List<CallHistory>>(result);
        YelloAdminDbContext db = new YelloAdminDbContext();
        if (callHistory != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in callHistory.ToList())
            {

                int Id = int.Parse(item.Login);
                var note = db.Note.OrderByDescending(i => i.Id).Where(i => i.LoginId == Id).FirstOrDefault();
                if (note != null && note.LoginId == Id)
                {
                    var temp = note.Comments.ToList();
                    return PartialView(temp);
                }
                else
                    return Content("No Comments");

                }

            }
        return Content("No Comments");
        }
```

View

```
      @model IEnumerable<MyYello.Admin.Models.CallNote>


   <table>
<tr>

    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Comments)
    </th>

    <th></th>
</tr>

 @foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>

    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comments)
    </td>


    </tr>
  }

  </table>
```

Comment: What is the Type of `Comments` ? you need to pass a list of `CallNote` to your view.

Comment: it is a string . but the issue is with Ienumerable here

Comment: `return PartialView(temp)` here you are passing a list of `Comments` but view is expecting list of `CallNote`. Either you have to change the controller or view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are reuturning List of type **Commments**:

```
var temp = note.Comments.ToList();
                    return PartialView(temp);
```

while in your view is strongly typed to Model of type `IEnumerable<MyYello.Admin.Models.CallNote>`

In View you have written, so it conflicts you View is expecting different type while you are passing different type:

```
   @model IEnumerable<MyYello.Admin.Models.CallNote>
```

you should be returning `IEnumerable<MyYello.Admin.Models.CallNote>` from your action or if you need to pass Comments type then change in View :

```
@model List<MyYello.Admin.Models.Comments>
```

Comment: Now it is giving this error

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Char]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyYello.Admin.Models.CallNote]'.